# Dynamic Bezier drawing in a spritekit game - Best (performance) approach?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, sprite-kit, bezier

I am not an iOS developer, I just started to implement my game, that I have done in flash, hoping that it will be super fast using the native environment.

The project is a 2d game that has a lot of dynamic bezier drawing based on the user's interaction. Basically I draw dynamic blobs (amoeba type of shapes).

First I tried Swift, which is very similar to actionscript, but it turned out, Apple won't be able to accept apps built with Swift before the final release of Xcode6 and as I want release my game before September I went to objective C route.

I wanted to use sprite kit because of the integrated physics engine, sprite hierarchy, etc.

I tried to use SKSphapeNode for drawing, but I realised it very quickly, it is not suitable for my needs. (cannot draw a stroke if it is thicker than 2 pixels, it has memory leaks etc.)

So I used UIBezierPath that I put into an UIImage, but I am not happy with the performance as I have to create a new UIImage with the new dynamically generated bezier shape.

These are the options I found so far:

1. SkShapeNode - not suitable for my game
2. UIBezierPath - UIImage > I have to create a new UIImage every frame, so it is slow
3. OpenGL - I haven't tried it yet, I am not sure it is possible to use it with Sprite kit
4. CALayer - I am trying to integrate it with spritekit at the moment, but I have a feeling I will have the same problem that I had with the UIImage approach.

Does anybody have any idea, tip what approach would be the best performance-wise?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: while I have never made an iOS app, I would say that as a developer, it's your responsibility to try all four and find out which one is best. Then probably also blog about it.

Comment: Well, I made many-many games and apps in the past 20 years, but not with the native iOS SDK, so I am very familiar with my responsibilities Mike, but thank you for reminding me anyway :)
I guess when I finish my game, I should share the revenue with you too? ;)

Comment: don't be silly (unless you really want to share the revenue ;). But, the Stackoverflow FAQ does explicitly say that questions about "what should I do?" are bad questions. Usually they get closed (it's one of the presupplied "close this because..." reasons). 20 years experience or not, the advice would still be the same. Try everything =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to create a lightning effect with using SpriteKit, so check out my article about that: https://andreygordeev.com/2014/11/01/lightning-with-srite-kit.html

Some of the approaches use `UIBezierPath`, so may be you find that useful.

Comment: Thank you Andrey, I checked your blog, it was very useful. I appreciate your help.

Comment: sadly the blog is offline now

Comment: @RanaTallal Here is the source code: https://github.com/andrew8712/SpriteKitLightning-Swift

Comment: The page also available here: http://andreygordeev.blogspot.ru/2014/11/sprite-kit-lightning.html